# Read CSV file to nested objects

Tags: c#, linq, csv, group-by, csvhelper

I have CSV file like

```
Title|Column|Value
A|Z1|1
A|Z1|2
A|Z1|3
A|Z2|1
A|Z2|5
B|Z3|4
B|Z3|6
....
```

I want to read this csv file into the following class hierarchy:
(I want to end up with a List of `MyClass`)

```cs
class MyClass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
}
class Column
{
    public string Column { get; set; }
    public List<Value> Values { get; set; }
}
class Value
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I am not able to comprehend how to achieve this.
What I tried up till now is:

```cs
class DTO
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Column { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

List<DTO> records = new List<DTO>();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(model.Path))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    records = csv.GetRecords<DTO>().ToList();
}

var temp = records
    .GroupBy(x => x.Title)
    .Select(y => new
    {
        Title = y.Key,
        Columns = y.SelectMany(x => new { x.Column, x.Value }) //I am not sure how to proceed from here
    });
```

The issue I am facing is how can I further group by on the columns and get the values, or if I should be using another approach?

Some more explanation on the csv structure:
There can be multiple Values for each column, and there can be multiple columns for each Title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There can be multiple Values for each column, and there can be multiple columns for each Title.

That means that you have to repeat the first step and `GroupBy` again by columns.  You also should use your types that you already implemented for this. Don't use anonymous types:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> temp = records
    .GroupBy(x => x.Title)
    .Select(y => new MyClass
    {
        Title = y.Key,
        Columns = y.GroupBy(x => x.Column)
        .Select( c => new Column
        {
            Column_ = c.Key,
            Values = c.Select(v => new Value
            {
                Value_ = v.Value
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList()
    });

    temp.Dump();
```

Result (from the LINQPad Dump):

[image]

PS. I changed the names of the properties, because the compiler does not allow them to be named exactly as the class is.

```
class Column
{
    public string Column_ { get; set; }
    public List<Value> Values { get; set; }
}
class Value
{
    public string Value_ { get; set; }
}
```